# npm parse yaml to object with array instead of named objects

Tags: typescript

I'm using [npm parse yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml) to parse yaml to an object and I get a group of named objects instead of an array. This is caused by the objects not having been prefixed with a dash (I think).

How can I convert the group of named objects to an array, or tell the parsers that this is what I want?

Yaml (partial):

```yaml
jobs:
  job-a:
    property-1: value

  job-b:
    property-1: different value
```

Using `const parsed = YAML.parse(content)` gives me this object (JSON representation my own):

```
 object.jobs = {
   "job-a": { "property-1": "value"},
   "job-b": { "property-1": "different value"} 
 }
```

So the jobs object contains properties "job-a" and "job-b" instead of an array that I can iterate on.

I've been looking at the docs, but that seems more focused on the setup of creating the YAML and I cannot figure out how to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to check [YAML syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html).
YAML example you've presented contains exactly the object "jobs" with properties "job-a" and "job-b".
If you need an array, you should modify your YAML by adding list of jobs:

```
jobs:
  - job-a:
      property-1: value
  - job-b:
      property-1: different value
```

So, `YAML.parse(content)` will give you array inside `jobs`:

```
{
  "jobs": [
    {
      "job-a": {
        "property-1": "value"
      }
    },
    {
      "job-b": {
        "property-1": "different value"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes. That is what I was thinking. The thing is, I don’t have control over the yaml that I got send in, but still wanted to parse this as an array instead of properties. 